# sizing a DC bias RF choke for a differential antenna + PA

Tags: differential, load, impedance-matching, pcb-antenna, choke

Trying to figure an antenna for the Si4012 RF chip. Page 26 of https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/application-notes/AN639.pdf talks about feeding the two sides of the loop antenna through two pull-up inductors (LP and LM) which it fails to provide any values for.

I have read [here](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/analogwire/archive/2014/04/23/when-to-use-an-rf-choke-vs-an-inductor) that I should

> Select a sufficiently high inductance value. (Z = 2 * pi * f * L)
>   Select an impedance (Z) that is much larger than the load resistance.

This usually translates into "make it tenfold"

In my design, |Z_load| is somewhere between 500 and 600 ohm (PA and adapted differential antenna). Wouldn't it be required to pick an inductor having its impedance in the 5k - 6k ohm interval in order to actually be effective at blocking the fundamental + first few armonics ? -

- Meaning 2.2 uH with a SRF of more than 1736 MHz in order to cut out everything to and including the 3rd armonic. The trouble is I am unable to find on the market such a large inductor at that kind of SRF. They usually go to 100+ MHz SRF at 2.2 uH. Perhaps I am miscalculating something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since the impedance is **differential**, you actually only need **half the impedance** on each side.
2. You don't need to "cut" harmonic power in these inductors - in fact, you want to **absorb** harmonics. Therefore an SRF above the **fundamental** is acceptable.
3. The third harmonic is 3x the fundamental, not 4x. (The first harmonic **is** the fundamental) Just FYI - it does not matter in this case!
4. Small PCB loop antennas are already lossy, so you don't need "tenfold" reactance or a super Q for, say, less than 1dB of additional loss. Without calculating, I would guesstimate 5x to be workable.  (It will slightly "pull" your antennna's center frequency though.)
5. Based on the above, an RF inductor like [the 470nH from Johanson](https://www.johansontechnology.com/downloads/jti-cat-ww-ind.pdf) is a workable candidate:

[image: 0805 RF Capacitors]